# Google map in div with column-count css property results in unusable map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, column-count

I'm embedding a Google map with the javascript api v3 in a div that's split into columns using the column-count css property.  The map works when it's in the first column, but if it's a later element in another column, the map tiles don't appear.

Codepen with working map in first column: http://codepen.io/dan-sil/pen/grRKJz

```
  <div class="widgets-holder">
    <div id="map"></div>
      END MAP
    </div>
     <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      MAP:

    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
  </div>
```

Codepen with broken map in second column: http://codepen.io/dan-sil/pen/bpRKJQ

```
  <div class="widgets-holder">
     <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      MAP:
    <div id="map"></div>
      END MAP
    </div>

    <div class="widget">
      WIDGET
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I only need this to work in Chrome since it's being embedded in a chromecast app. If only all of my projects could go without IE support... :)

Comment: I see a map in the second codepen (at least in Chrome), what browser(s) do you see issues with?

Comment: @geocodezip Interesting!  I'm using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.49.  Here's screenshots of what it looks like for me: https://imgur.com/a/rX1a5

Comment: I also tested it in 49.0.2623.108 and the map isn't working.  Mind sharing what version you're using?

Comment: 51.0.2689.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: You're right!! I installed Chrome 51.0.2687.0 dev (64-bit) and it works. Now to figure out why...